react-native-receive-sharing-intent giving error "java.lang.string android.content.intent.getaction() on a null object reference"
In react native, I have implemented react-native-receive-sharing-intent package for receiving photos from other app. When I try to share the image from android mobile photos to my app, it shows below error.

  attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.string
  android.content.intent.getaction()' on a null object reference


I have followed the link https://ajith-ab.github.io/react-native-receive-sharing-intent/docs/android
My Code is,
ReceiveSharingIntent.getReceivedFiles(files => { 
             
              console.log('SharedData');
              if(files) {
                console.log(files);
              }
             
              
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log('Error receiving shared data:', error);
               ReceiveSharingIntent.clearReceivedFiles();
            },
            'com.myapp' // App Group identifier 
          );
          ReceiveSharingIntent.clearReceivedFiles();

But same error. How to fix this issue?
